# How to inject JSONConvert into .NET Core 3.1 service class?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I need to serialize some classes in .NET Core 3.1 service class (not controller).

I can simply use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` which could do the job for me:

```
private void LogEvent(object properties, LogLevel logLevel)
{
    var message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(properties);

    _logger.Log(logLevel, message);
}
```

But I have to use `Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter` as we need the enums as string.

I can use below code to achieve this:

```
var message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(properties, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Converters = { new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter() },
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        });
```

As you can see this will create a new object every time this method gets hit. Not sure if this is the right approach.

Can we define JSONConvert in startup class and inject it on service class where I can use `Serialize` object?

Something like:

```
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not inject `JSONConvert` because it is static class.

But you can do something like this

```
public interface IProxyJSONConvert {
   public string SerializeObject(object obj);
}
```

```
public class ProxyJSONConvert : IProxyJSONConvert  {
   public string SerializeObject(object obj)
    {
      return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(properties);
    }
}
```

And In Startup

```
services.AddScoped<IProxyJSONConvert, ProxyJSONConvert>();
```

Now in controller you can pass this in controller and then service

You can modify according to your need